# Where to download latest Android-SDK for Ubuntu other than Android.com

Tags: android, downloads, android-studio, android-sdk

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 OS which is offline and does not have an internet connection. I have downloaded and installed Android Studio 3.0.1 from another PC to that offline OS. I have also downloaded android-SDK-tools which I don't know what to do with.

When I start Android Studio it asks for the Android SDK path, but I can't find any link to download it. From my searching, the latest version is 26, but I could not find any direct way to download it.

**TL;DR**

**Is there any link to download the latest version of Android-SDK for GNU/Linux operating systems like Ubuntu?**

**Important:** Unfortunately, Google does not let users from my location download anything from android.com through its website nor apt-get nor android studio built-in downloads, so please mind this stipulation in your answers.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: Not being able to download from Google, nor being able to use apt-get will make this very hard. Perhaps getting a VPN to get around this might be the easiest way (?)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) and then install android-sdk from it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make

umake android android-sdk
```

Comment: Yes it may help. but it;s not possible for me where i live. is there any way to go around with this google limitations?